# How to get hash from XML for signing in java

Tags: java, xml-dsig

I have to create an application which has XML data and creates Hash for signing and send the hash to an API to get the raw signature for XML and append signature for XML in Java How can I achieve this.

The same thing can be done in .Net by overriding `SignedXml` class like this

```
public class CustomSignedXml: SignedXml
{
    public CustomSignedXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc) : base(xmlDoc)
    {
    }
    public void ComputeSignature()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(SignedXml).GetMethod("BuildDigestedReferences", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
        SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

        SignatureDescription signatureDescription = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(SignedInfo.SignatureMethod) as SignatureDescription;
        if (signatureDescription == null)
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_SignatureDescriptionNotCreated");

        HashAlgorithm hashAlg = signatureDescription.CreateDigest();
        if (hashAlg == null)
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_CreateHashAlgorithmFailed");
        MethodInfo methodInfo2 = typeof(SignedXml).GetMethod("GetC14NDigest", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        byte[] hashvalue = (byte[])methodInfo2.Invoke(this, new object[] { hashAlg });
        var signature = GetSignatureFromServer(hashvalue);
        m_signature.SignatureValue = signature;
    }
}
```

And use `CustomSignedXml` class to sign using following meathod

```
public string GetSignedXml(string xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 PublicCertificate)
{
    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocumentToSign = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocumentToSign.LoadXml(xmlDoc);

        CustomSignedXml signedXml = new CustomSignedXml(xmlDocumentToSign);

        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(GetKeyInfoData(PublicCertificate));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        var xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        xmlDocumentToSign.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDocumentToSign.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        return xmlDocumentToSign.OuterXml;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

How can I do the same in JAVA

Comment: Your code should be pretty much the same. Just import the relevant java.security.* libraries

Comment: I have done XML signing in java, but the point here is to get the hash for which PKCS#1 signature is generated and added to `<SignatureValue>` tag, AFAIK it is not same as the Base64 encoded digest value which is given in `<DigestValue>` tag of signed XML.

Comment: You can reference my project. I think it is fit your request! https://github.com/chenhuang511/xml-dsig-sign-hash